# Adding elements of one list to specific places in another list: Python

Tags: python-3.x

Pretty much all questions I saw re: this problem were more about concatenation or doing something like adding spaces between elements in a list.

Suppose I had:

```
a = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
b = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

I'd like for an element in b to be appended after each element in a, so that I would end up with `c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`.  How would I go about this?

Answer (score 3):

```
c = [] 
for i in range(len(a)):
   c.append(a[i])
   c.append(b[i])
```

This would require `a` to be the same length as `b`. You would have to add to this slightly if they were different, but it would be the same idea.

If your goal was just wanting to get a sorted list of both `a` and `b`...

```
c = sorted(list(set().union(a, b)))
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`roundrobin`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/itertools.html?highlight=roundrobin) recipe in `itertools` but that is a bit overkill for your example but does work with unequal lengths.
For equal length sublists then all you need to do is `zip()` and flatten:

```
>>> [n for p in zip(a, b) for n in p]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Or using `itertools.chain.from_iterable`:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> list(it.chain.from_iterable(zip(a, b)))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Alternatively, you can write your own generator:

```
def gen(a, b):
    for x, y in zip(a, b):
        yield x
        yield y

>>> list(gen(a, b))
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I like the idea of a generator but zip() allocates a list which kind of defeats the purpose

Comment: @minitotent `zip()` doesn't allocate a list in Py3, it is equivalent to `itertools.izip()` in Py2.

Comment: oh my bad, I looked up the python2 version, +1 for a relevant generator

Answer (score 2):

Looping with an [insert()](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html) works and is relatively straightforward:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    a.insert(2*(i)+1, b[i])
```

note list.insert() needs to move every subsequent list entry back one position in memory which is quite inefficient for large lists, a deque (think doubly linked list) from collections.deque may be a better choice.

If you are trying to allocate a new list:

```
c = []
for i in range(len(a)):
    c.append(a[i])
    c.append(b[i])
```

Also notice that this specific implementation only works for lists of equal length.

Answer (score 1):

May be this could help ...

```
def alternateListInsert(a,b):
    fIndex = 1
    for i in range(len(b)):
        a.insert(fIndex,b[i]);
        fIndex += 2

    return a
```